# K&R C - Testing Wordcount program

Tags: c, unix, gcc, wc

The following code is from K&R The C Programming Language.

I compile the code with `gcc wordCount.c` on a UNIX system through putty. After compiling I run `./a.out` and regardless of what arguments I pass after `./a.out` it returns nothing and loops infinitely.

I am a C beginner, and I am very lost but very enthusiastic to learn. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
/* This program is a bare-bones version of the UNIX program wc. */

#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1 /* inside a word */
#define OUT 0 /* outside a word */

/* count lines, words, and characters in input */
int main(void) {
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state;

    state = OUT;
    nl = nw = nc = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            state = OUT;
        else
        if (state == OUT) {
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int main(void)` says the program ignores its arguments.  It reads its standard input.  Type some words at it.  On several lines.  Indicate EOF (end of file) with Control-D.  It should report the three numbers at the end.

Comment: Ah! Makes sense, thank you very much!

Comment: Try `echo a b c | ./a.out` **or** `./a.out < a b c`

Comment: echo a b c | ./a.out  or something like: cat textFile.txt | ./a.out works as well. This is also what I was looking for. Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: **Note:** you can add `if (state != OUT) nl++;` before the `printf` statement to account for files without a POSIX end of file (`newline` terminating the last line). As the code is now, the line count will be 1-short with a non-POSIX end of file.